# tkinter - Can't find a usable tk.tcl

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try the following code :

```
import Tkinter
Tkinter._test()
```

I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3835, in _test
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1818, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
/usr/local/lib/tcl8.6/tk8.6 /usr/local/lib/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tk8.6 /lib/tk8.6 /usr/library



This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

I tried to reinstall Tkinter, but it still give the same error.

Can I have help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Install python-tk and I think you will solve your problems.

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Comment: I already tried `apt-get install python-tk`, but it still give the same error

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has a different name in Python 2 and 3.

- Python 2: `import Tkinter`
- Python 3: `import tkinter`

Unless you have a very good reason, use Python 3. Make sure tkinter is installed by running `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` and use the `python3` command in the terminal.

Comment: I use python2.7, so no need to install `python3-tk`.

Comment: @ZeiadBadawy Again, if there's no good reason, use Python 3.

Comment: I just tried to use Python 3 and it gives the same error. The problem is not with the `tkinter` module, it is with `tk` like it is shown in the last line of my error :  `This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.` I don't know what I did with `tk`, but I should fix the problem because I can't use my GUI programs and the python idle.

Comment: Are the following packages installed? `sudo apt-get install tk8.6 libtk8.6 tcl8.6 libtcl8.6`